# Hide and show element onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am working on a project whereby i want to make certain form fields invisible by default and become visible when a user clicks on a certain button however i cannot get it to work. .

> **EDIT**
>
> > So i went to youtube to find something that might help and i found tutorial that was helpful. However when i implemented it, i still kinda have a rough patch to figure out.

Here is my code

```js
function myFunction(x){
  if (x==0){
    document.getElementById("id_73").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_80").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("id_70").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (x==1){
    document.getElementById("id_80").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_70").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_73").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction1(x){
  if (x==0){
    document.getElementById("id_74").style.display = "block";
  }
  else if (x==1){
    document.getElementById("id_74").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_radio" id="id_68">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_68" for="input_68">Designation
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>

        <div id="cid_68" class="form-input jf-required">
          <div class="form-multiple-column" data-columncount="2" role="group" aria-labelledby="label_68" data-component="radio">
            <span class="form-radio-item" >
              <span class="dragger-item"></span>
              <input type="radio" aria-describedby="label_68" class="form-radio validate[required]" id="input_68_0" name="q68_typeA68" value="staff" required="" onclick="myFunction(0)"/>
              <label id="label_input_68_0" for="input_68_0">Staff</label>
            </span>

            <span class="form-radio-item">
              <span class="dragger-item"></span>
              <input type="radio" aria-describedby="label_68" class="form-radio validate[required]" id="input_68_1" name="q68_typeA68" value="student" required="" onclick="myFunction(1)"/>
              <label id="label_input_68_1" for="input_68_1">Student</label>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_textbox" id="id_73" style="display:none;">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_73" for="input_73">Staff Id
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_73" class="form-input jf-required">
          <input type="text" id="input_73" name="q73_typeA73" data-type="input-textbox" class="form-textbox validate[required]" data-defaultvalue="" size="20" value="" data-component="textbox" aria-labelledby="label_73" required=""/>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_textbox" id="id_80" style="display: none;">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_80" for="input_80">Matric Number
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_80" class="form-input jf-required">
          <input type="text" id="input_80" name="q80_typeA80" data-type="input-textbox" class="form-textbox validate[required]" data-defaultvalue="" size="20" value="" data-component="textbox" aria-labelledby="label_80" required=""/>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_radio" id="id_70" style="display: none;">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_70" for="input_70">Library User?
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_70" class="form-input jf-required">
          <div class="form-multiple-column" data-columncount="2" role="group" aria-labelledby="label_70" data-component="radio">

            <span class="form-radio-item">
              <span class="dragger-item"></span>
              <input type="radio" aria-describedby="label_70" class="form-radio validate[required]" id="input_70_0" name="q70_typeA70" value="yes" required="" onclick="myFunction1(0)"/>
              <label id="label_input_70_0" for="input_70_0">Yes</label>
            </span>

            <span class="form-radio-item">
              <span class="dragger-item"></span>
              <input type="radio" aria-describedby="label_70" class="form-radio validate[required]" id="input_70_1" name="q70_typeA70" value="No" required="" onclick="myFunction1(1)"/>
              <label id="label_input_70_1" for="input_70_1">No</label>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_textbox" id="id_74" style="display: none;">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_74" for="input_74"> Library Card Id
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_74" class="form-input jf-required">
          <input type="text" id="input_74" name="q74_typeA74" data-type="input-textbox" class="form-textbox validate[required]" data-defaultvalue="" size="20" value="" data-component="textbox" aria-labelledby="label_74" required=""/>
        </div>
      </li>
```

The problem i now face is that whenever i select student **student** as designation and i select yes for **library user**,  a bug is introduced and i can't seem to fix it. Any help will be appreciated

> **P.S:** I am not a javascript developer, so my code might seem raunchy so please go easy on me

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `document.getElementById("id_74").style.display = "none";`
to `MyFunction`. This will get rid of the library key option if the user decides to switch back to the staff option. The edited function is below:

```
function myFunction(x){
  if (x==0){
    document.getElementById("id_73").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_80").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("id_70").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("id_74").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (x==1){
    document.getElementById("id_80").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_70").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_73").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This fix is great, but there is one problem. If you switch back to student from staff after picking yes on student, the library key box will be missing, and the only way of getting it to appear again would be to press yes again(Of course, the yes button will already be highlighted). One way to fix this would be to add booleans to detect whether the yes button was previously pressed.

To do this, declare a variable before your function like this:

```
let isYesPressed = false;
```

Then switch its value to true when yes is pressed, and switch its value to false when no is pressed. (This is in `myFunction1`):

```
 if (x==0){
    isYesPressed = true; 
    document.getElementById("id_74").style.display = "block";
  }
  if(x==1){
     isYesPressed = false;
  }
```

Then check to see if yes was pressed in `MyFunction`

```
  else if (x==1){
    if(isYesPressed){
       document.getElementById("id_74").style.display = "block";
     }
    document.getElementById("id_80").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_70").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("id_73").style.display = "none";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Radio Buttons</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
```